# Add a chat system to Laravel website using livewire

Tags: laravel, web, chat, system, project

I am working on a project using laravel 8 and livewire , i have come to the part where i have to add a chat system to this project.
I was going to use livewire but i have heard that , it's a little bit risky to use it what fo you think about that ? in case it's true what is your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

I could have commented but I don't have enough reputation to comment so I replied here.
Yes, you can make a chat system with Livewire.
I highly recommend you to watch videos from Laravel Daily for Laravel Issues.
He created a video about the chat system with Livewire.
Here is the link: [Laravel Livewire: Simple Chat Room Component](https://youtu.be/PREOLFhmqBw)

Comment: yes I know, it's from laravel daily that I heard that it's a bit risky and not scalable to use livewire for chat system

Comment: It's not actually scalable for doing this with Livewire. I prefer you go with sockets.
I just answered if it can be done with Livewire or not.